# ValueError: shapes (4,1) and (5,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 5 (dim 0)

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, vector

I am making a simple network to solve XOR and I am getting an error. Here is my code

```
def back_prop(a2,z0,z1,z2,y):
    delta2=z2-y
    Delta2=np.matmul(z1.T,delta2)
    delta1=(delta2.dot(W2[1:,:]).T)*sigmoid_derivative(a1)
  
    Delta1=np.matmul(z0.T,delta1)
  
    delta=np.matmul(Delta1,W1[1:,:])
    return delta2,Delta2, Delta1
```

and the error it is giving me is ValueError: shapes (4,1) and (5,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 5 (dim 0)

I tried to look up the problem, but I couldn't find any solutions that worked. Could you please help? Thanks!

Comment: Where did you "look up the problem"?  Did you just look for solutions, or did you look to understand the issue?  What did you try. But first, did you look up the official `np.matmul` documentation?  If so, did you understand what is said about dimension compatibility?  And what you do expect the result to be?  given (5,1) and (4,1) arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Your error can't be reproduced if you don't provide the input parameters.

That said, your error message tells you exactly what the issue is: `matmul` is standard matrix multiplication, which you can't perform between 4x1 and 5x1 matrices. Transposing `delta*` matrices instead of `z*` could fix the error, but it is up to you to check if this is really the numerical result you want.

Comment: it says the error was on the line     delta1=(delta2.dot(W2[1:,:]).T)*sigmoid_derivative(a1)
 not matmul

Comment: Samuel, you didn't show the FULL error, so we had to guess which line.  `matmul` and `dot` have the same dimension requirements (for 2d arrays).  Why didn't you look at the `np.dot` docs?